# Epsilon-Delta Proof Of a Function - Do Epsilon and Delta decrease (resp. increase) With Respect to Each Other?

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

I am a first year Mathematics student. And during a lecture we were taking a look at the limit of a function and I asked my lecturer if in the ε- proof of limit of a function, can we always say that if ε is increasing(respectively decreasing), so does . In other words, if ε is increasing(respectively decreasing), does  always increase(respectively decrease)? And we couldn't really be sure about it in the lecture so I wanted to ask it here, to everyone.

[image: Epsilon-Delta Proof]

I am not sure about which tags I should've put for this question so let me know if this question is related to some tag(s) which I didn't include for this question.

Any kind of help is very appreciated.

Comment: You will likely find it helpful to consider a constant function. (There are about five different functions which together will get you through most of first-year analysis as examples and counterexamples. The constant function is one of them.)

Comment: To begin with, your graph is incorrect for a general function. The two $\delta$ intervals are exactly equal in width and so are the two $\varepsilon$ intervals, and there is no guarantee that the function will cooperate by passing through all three intersection points as shown in your graph.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Out of curiosity, what are the other 4?

Comment: By "together" I don't really mean "the answer will always be one of these", but rather "most answers will be a composition of these, although you should really understand exactly what makes each one tick, so that you can adapt it where needed". Anyway, my shot at a decent five would be: the constant $0$ except for a spike in the middle ($f(x) = 0$ for $x < 0$, then linearly interpolate up to $f(1) = 1$, then linearly interpolate back down to $f(2) = 0$); $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ on various domains (perhaps with a value chosen for $x=0$); $\exp$; $\sin \frac{1}{x}$; $x \mapsto x^2$.

Comment: I guess I haven't mentioned understanding that "multiplying by $x$ squashes down towards $0$", but I could handwave that away by using "multiplying by $x^2$" which often works instead and which I did mention. I intended the mention of $\exp$ to include the fact that "exp is perfectly smooth, you can use it in a piecewise definition if you need a function to smoothly interpolate somewhere", and $\sin \frac{1}{x}$ to include an understanding of $x \sin \frac{1}{x}$ and $x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x^2}$, for example. I claim all of this merely comes under the "understand what makes each one tick" rider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $\varepsilon-\delta$ limit only requires the existence of a $\delta$, it doesn't put any restrictions on it. Perhaps most importantly, it doesn't require that $\delta$ is unique.

As a bit of an extreme example, consider the constant function $f(x) = c$ and let's look at what happens in the neighbourhood of $x_0 = 0$. Of course we already know that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = c$, but notice that for the $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ we can choose *any* positive $\delta$ we like, and in particular we could make $\delta$ increase as $\varepsilon$ decreases and our proof will still work.

For example, let $\delta = \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$. Then for $|x - 0| = |x| < \delta$, $|f(x) - f(0)| = |c - c| = 0 < \frac{1}{\delta} = \varepsilon$.

Of course we could also choose a tighter bound on $\delta$, and in general you will find that usually the $\delta$ will be mostly non-increasing with decreasing $\varepsilon$, but it's not a fundamental property.

Answer (score 3):

[The first answer you received](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4576008/139123) is correct and demonstrates why $\delta$ does not need to increase or decrease as $\varepsilon$ does.

I think part of the reason for the confusion on this point in the first place is the use of an inappropriate graph of the relationship of $\delta$ and $\varepsilon$ to each other and to the function whose limit you want to take.

I don't know where that graph came from (not from a textbook, I hope!)
but I would propose to modify the graph as follows:

[image]

The difference is that the portion of the function bracketed by the $\delta$ intervals is strictly *inside* the portion of the function bracketed by the $\varepsilon$ intervals, so that neither the upper line $y=L+\varepsilon$ nor the lower line
$y=L-\varepsilon$ touches the portion of the function graph between
$x=c-\delta$ and $x=c+\delta.$

If you study this diagram carefully it should be relatively easy to understand that you can increase this value of $\varepsilon$ as much as you want without having to change $\delta$ at all.
Conversely you can make $\delta$ as small as you want without changing $\varepsilon.$

The original diagram simply does not work in general, because for a given $c$ and $\varepsilon$ it is not generally possible to find $\delta$ such that
$f(c-\delta) = L-\varepsilon,$ $f(c) = L,$ and $f(c+\delta) = L+\varepsilon.$
For an extreme example of this, consider the case where $f(c)$ is the maximum value of the function. The line $y=L+\varepsilon$ will pass clear over the maximum point of the function without touching the curve anywhere, which makes it obvious that you can't have $f(c+\delta) = L+\varepsilon.$

What is far more important than how close $f(c+\delta)$ is to $L+\varepsilon$
is the requirement that **all** of the graph of the function between
$x=c-\delta$ and $x=c+\delta$
must lie between the lines $y=L+\varepsilon$ and $y=L-\varepsilon.$
If the function ever wanders outside the region between those two horizontal lines while traveling between the two vertical lines,
that value of $\delta$ is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Well with not much thinking, I have found another counterexample for it. And for beginners like me, I tried to visualize it. This purple curve is a graph of a function and see, as ε decreased,  increased instead. I hope I haven't made any mistakes on this.

[image: 1]

Also, I made it on Microsoft Paint so I am open for any suggestions for mathematical drawings.

Comment: This is not a correct example. The value $\delta_2$ does not satisfy the conditions required for $\delta$ when $\varepsilon=\varepsilon_2,$ because part of the purple curve between $x=c-\delta_2$ and $x=c+\delta_2$ lies outside the lines $y=L-\varepsilon_2$ and $y=L+\varepsilon_2$.

Comment: Oh right, then I should be looking for the area which the graph is in that area. Instead, I was looking at the interception points of (L±ε) and (c±δ), then that area between those was what I was looking for. That made a better understanding of the definition for me. Thanks a lot @DavidK .

Comment: The other thing you still seem to be doing is using the horizontal and vertical lines as cross-hairs that intersect at a function point. That works for $x=c$ and $y=L$ (if the function is continuous) but not generally for the other lines, and it can distort your intuition about delta-epsilon proofs in various bad ways.